# Evaluating $\int x!\left(\frac1x+\frac{1}{x-1}+...+\frac11\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

A friend of mine told me to evaluate the following integral....
$$\int  x!\left(\frac1x+\frac{1}{x-1}+...+\frac11\right)dx$$

I have two questions here

$1)$ Does the integral even actually exist in terms of elementary functions?
This is because  $x!$ is defined for integer values..

$2)$If the integral exists , how to evaluate it?
Multiplying makes the expression even more complicated....So , I tried writing this as $e^{\ln x!+\ln\left(\frac1x+\frac{1}{x-1}+...+\frac11\right)}$

But I don't know how to proceed further? Any help would be appreciated.....

Comment: Just like to point out, if you get a common denominator for the terms in the parentheses, that could be $x!$. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: While $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$, the term in parentheses doesn't seem to make sense unless $x\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The expression $\frac1x+\frac{1}{x-1}+...+\frac11$ simply doesn't make sense when $x$ isn't an integer.

Comment: What do the points ... replace.

Comment: And there are no integration limits.

Comment: No integration limits..I too find this expression confusing as $x$ must be natural...

Comment: Your friend is messing with you.

Comment: maybe instead of the parenthesis you want an analytic continuation for the harmonic numbers?

Comment: You can either regard $x!$ as $\Gamma(x+1)$ or you can use $x! (1/x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \cdots (1)$.  Either way, the expression makes sense.  I do not understand the comments saying $1/x +1(x-1) +$ etc. requires $x$ to be an integer.  Why?  It seems to be the other way around.

Comment: @awkward because if $x\notin\Bbb N$ then doesnt exists $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x-n=1$, so the last term in the parenthesis cannot be $1$, that is: the dots in the parenthesis are not meaningful.

Comment: @Masacroso, you are correct!  I apologize for being slow to catch on.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\psi(z) = \frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}$, then we can resolve your ambiguous notation with the following.

$$\psi(z) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{z+k}$$

$$\psi(n+1) - \psi(1) = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}$$

so that naturally

$$\psi(x+1) - \psi(1) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x-1} + ... + 1$$

Therefore the integral you want to evaluate is

$$\int_a^z \Gamma(x+1)(\psi(x+1) - \psi(1))\,dx$$

which becomes at best

$$\Gamma(z+1) - \Gamma(a+1) - \psi(1)\int_a^z \Gamma(x+1)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give this question an actual meaning: at the moment, there are definition issues in $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}+\ldots+1$ if $x\not\in\mathbb{N}$. We may start from the Weierstrass product for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):
$$ \Gamma(z+1) = e^{-\gamma z}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{z/n} \tag{1}$$
and by applying $\frac{d}{dz}\log(\cdot)$ to both sides we have:
$$ \psi(z+1)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)} = -\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right]\tag{2} $$
hence:

$$ \frac{d}{dz}(z!) = \Gamma'(z+1) = \Gamma(z+1)\psi(z+1) = z!\left[-\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right)\right]\tag{3} $$
and if $z\in\mathbb{N}$ the RHS of $(3)$ equals $z!\left[-\gamma+H_z\right]$.

Comment: Looks like we'll need the electron microscope to know who posted first, lol

Comment: @james.nixon: lol, that happens quite often :) (+1) to you.